# An exception of type 'System.InvalidCastException'

Tags: c#, excel

Today I made ​​an update of ms office, and from 2007 to 2013. Before the update everything worked perfectly. When I debug the code I get the error on the first line. Can somebody help me with this issue?

Code:

```
Excel.Application xlApp = new Excel.Application();
Excel.Workbook xlWorkbook = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(excelPad);
Excel._Worksheet xlWorksheet = xlWorkbook.Sheets[1];
Excel._Worksheet xlWorksheet2 = xlWorkbook.Sheets[2];
Excel.Range xlRange = xlWorksheet.UsedRange;
Excel.Range xlRangeClear = xlWorksheet.Range["A3:Y10000", Type.Missing];
Excel.Range xlRangeClear2 = xlWorksheet.Range["AC3:AJ10000", Type.Missing];
```

Here's the error:

> An exception of type 'System.InvalidCastException' occurred in ****.exe but was not handled in user code

Comment: which office interop version are you using?

Comment: Maybe after the update, you have to renew the reference as well. Remove the reference to the Excel application and add it again.

Comment: @DJ Burb: version 12

Comment: yeah, it seems like there is a version conflict.

Comment: @Sjips: i already tried this...

Comment: Remove the references to Microsoft Interop, then do a clean.  After the clean, re-add them.

Comment: @ DJ Burb: no succes...

Answer (score 0):

Likely the install of Excel 2013 has installed the new PIA (Primary Interop Assemblies) for Excel 2013. You can either:

1. Update your references to point to 2013 in the Visual Studio Solution
2. Update the registry to point to the PIA key (see [here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/dd052f27-20d6-4b6b-9d8b-fe4fd9c6b9fc/broke-excel-interop-com-assembly-after-installingremoving-2013-beta-release?forum=exceldev) for instructions)

Comment: but i want to keep 2013... do i need to delete the PIA key of 2007